# Jquery Ajax Json parsing

Tags: php, ajax, json

I am aware of about

> When you specify "json" the data argument to your callback will already be parsed. There is no need to invoke JSON.parse.

But I have a different issue,that is the below block of code works fine in one server,there is no issue in parsing of json and you can see that I didn't add 'dataType:json' in the ajax request.Since I didn't specify the datatype as json I should parse the response, right?

The problem is the same block of code do not work in another server, shows an error in console as

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character   
return window.JSON.parse( data );
```

What may be the real issue?

JSON from PHP

> {"returning":138,"new_visitor":439,"page_views":6776,"visits":3217,"pages_visits":1.9}

Jquery

```
$.ajax({
     url: 'includes/gapi.apis.php',
     data: {action: 'visits'},
     type: 'post',
     async:false,
     success: function(output1) {
        var obj1 = jQuery.parseJSON(output1);
     }
```

Comment: what does output1 look like when it is rendered? There is an error with the output by the sound of it

Comment: 1) Why don't you specify the `dataType` on the request, and 2) I can't help because I don't know what `ONE DIAMENSIONAL ARRAY` is or how it'll encode to JSON.

Comment: @izuriel hi ,ONE DIAMENSIONAL ARRAY is not a string ,I just used that for understanding what $data means.

Comment: Okay well, if I run tests here then `$data = array(1)` and `echo json_encode($data)` everything works fine for me. Do you mind elaborating on what you're storing in `$data` because that is most likely where the problem is.

Comment: Your json is probably corrupted by a warning or error message, show the returned data.

Comment: @Musa then how it works in my server?

Comment: Different servers may have different configurations

Comment: @Musa which configuration?

Comment: @SujathanR It doesn't matter really at this moment, all we need from you is to either see what you're encoding (and any other relevant data) or the response that your server is sending when the URL is requested. Understand that I'm not asking for things you can't show, if you can't paste the code then come up with something that's very similar and give us that instead.

Comment: @izuriel did you saw my updated question,if no this is the encode json returning from php '{"returning":138,"new_visitor":439,"page_views":6776,"visits":3217,"pages_visits":1.9}'

Comment: @SujathanR According to http://jsonlint.com/ your JSON is perfectly valid then. Is that the only thing you see in the response - no error or html or anything?